# OBIEE 11g : Retrieve list of recent dashboard

Tags: oracle11g, reporting, dashboard, obiee

I want a list of recent and most popular dashboard to be used in a new dashboard in OBIEE 11g.
Can anyone help me understand how can extract the list of those dashboard and use it in a new custom dashboard.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)